# Disable grid row click, admin

Tags: magento2, grid

How do I disable grid click? So I can only click "Edit" link.
[image]

I've tried changing the function in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php` to `return false;` but it didn't work.

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To remove row url on grid, you need to edit function **getRowUrl** in file Grid.php as below:

```
public function getRowUrl($row){
       return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried changing the function in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php to return false; but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

You can change the admin layout xml as like below., ie., `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/frontname_controller_action.xml`.

Add this code in the `<block>` tag.

```
<arguments>
  <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="path" xsi:type="string"></item>
  </argument>
</arguments>
```

Comment: How can I override the file? I use the Ultimo theme

Answer (score 0):

> My Ui-Component filename is **tickets_listing.xml**

```
<columns name="tickets_columns">
<!-- remove this section for disable grid click  -->
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">tickets_listing.tickets_listing.tickets_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item><!-- Action FIle NAme  -->
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
```

> And flush Magento cache and now it's disable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<settings>
    <editorConfig>
        <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>
    </editorConfig>
</settings>
```

This works for Magento 2.4