# Disable Clickable Link On Magento 2 Order Grid Rows or ID column

Tags: magento2.3, orders, grid, adminform

When our customer service people need to copy an order number from the Admin Order Grid, they try and highlight it with their cursor and copy it but that triggers the standard M2 click action to show the order.

I need to be able to remove the URL from the ID cell or alternatively the whole row in the order grid only. We can still edit the order by clicking the "edit" link but the whole row being clickable is causing problems.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225083/disable-grid-row-click-admin/308026#308026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns" class="SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component\Columns"/>
</listing>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Ui/Component/Columns.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Component;

class Columns extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns
{
    public function prepare()
    {
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        if (isset($config['childDefaults']['fieldAction'])) {
            unset($config['childDefaults']['fieldAction']);
        }
        $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great thank you. The only slight drawnback I hadn't thought about is that it also disables the drag ordering of columns.

Is there a way to still allow that do you think?

Comment: Not sure why not working for you. M2.3.4 "drag ordering of columns" working well after applied this modification.

Comment: Actually it's working ok now - I have no idea why!
Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer above caused some issues for me, as some column rows were missing after switching the "Columns" class to my custom implementation. Probably a conflict with another extension.

So instead I created a plugin for the "Columns" class and modified the "prepare" method:

*di.xml:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_plugin_magento_catalog_ui_component_listing_columns" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns" />
    </type>
</config>
```

*Columns.php*

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing;

class Columns
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @return \Closure
     */
    public function aroundPrepare(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        // Try to get the config
        $config = @$subject->getData('config');
        if ($config) {

            // Try to get a specific field that indicates that we are currently processing the product grid
            $childDefaultsFieldActionProvider = @$config['childDefaults']['fieldAction']['provider'];
            if ($childDefaultsFieldActionProvider === 'product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.actions') {

                // Unset the "fieldAction", which removes the "link" on the product grid rows
                if (isset($config['childDefaults']['fieldAction'])) {
                    unset($config['childDefaults']['fieldAction']);

                    // And save the updated config
                    $subject->setData('config', (array) $config);
                }
            }
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```